# What is the worst case complexity of the given program?

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

program takes as input a balanced binary search tree with n leaf nodes and computes the value of a function g(x) for each node x. If the cost of computing g(x) is min{no. of leaf-nodes in left-subtree of x, no. of leaf-nodes in right-subtree of x} then the worst-case time complexity of the program is

My solution :

For each internal node the maximum cost would be n/2. For every leaf node the cost is zero.

And number of internal nodes for a balanced binary tree are : leaf nodes - 1

So the total cost will be :

n/2 * (n-1)

O(n^2)

Am I right?

Comment: perhaps best answered on http://programmers.stackexchange.com? "If you have a question about... algorithm and data structure concepts"

Comment: what do you think the answer is and why do you think that?

Comment: @hexparrot - In its current form, this question would fare very poorly on Programmers.

Comment: Would it suddenly be in much better form if the A-B-C-D answers were removed and he instead asked "How would I determine the worst-case time complexity?"

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've added my solution

Comment: @ahbi I think that makes sense ... that would be my guess... but i got a low B in that class and it was many years ago

Comment: @JoranBeasley upvote and wait for an answer :p

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution. For the worst case the tree would happen to be a complete tree which you GOT RIGHT and therefore the number of leaf nodes would be n/2.

But it is the case for root node.

For nodes at level 1: total cost would be 2*n/4=n/2

For nodes at level 2: total cost would be 4*n/8=n/2

and so on till last level which is log(n) and cost would again be = n/2

Total Cost therefore in worst case is =n/2*log (n) = O(n*logn), In complete tree it can happen that the last level is not completely filled but in asymptotic analysis we ignore such intricate details.

Comment: you solution is lucid sumeet...I know I am commenting very late but you deserve upvote..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate g(x) of each node using divide and conquer technique. Solve left and right subtree recursively. Combine the results to obtain your solution.

Recurrence relation for time complexity is

T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(1)

which gives time complexity O(n)